# In Python, how to assert passed-in file object was opened with newline=''?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a function that takes in a file object, e.g.

```
def my_fn(file_obj):
    assert <what expression here?>, "file_obj must be opened with newline=''."
    ...
```

The first thing I want to do in the function is ensure that the passed-in file object was opened with `newline=''`. How do I do this? Thanks.

PS. I believe this question is only applicable to Python 3 because `newline=''` only exists in Python 3 (note it's different from the default `newline=None`).

Comment: It may be worth filing a bug report, this seems a sensible use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without parsing the source at runtime using ast I don't think it is going to be easy or possible at all to get the info from the file object, you could maybe make sure the newline was `None` or `""` by reading a line then checking the newlines attribute but I am not sure that the `newlines`  attribute is even always going to be available:

```
    next(f)
    if f.newlines is None:
        raise ValueError("...")
    else:
        f.seek(0)
```

But if you could only accept a file object from a function that takes a filename and open the file yourself so you would be in control:

```
def open_fle(f, mode="r"):
    with open(f, mode=mode,  newline="") as f:
         .....
```

Comment: The `newlines` attribute indeed isn't always available (it's only available on files opened in text mode).

Comment: @SimeonVisser, yes I was pretty sure it depended on the implementation, I don't see any way outside of maybe parsing the source at runtime to force the use of `newline=""`